# SQL Script Error when running query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, shell-exec

so I'm currently making a system to update database tables by downloading a SQL script from an API and then using the file to update the SQL tables. The file downloads fine. However, I think the issue lies with my SQL script.

**SQL Code:**

```sql
IF COL_LENGTH('sitesettings', 'backgroundColor') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE sitesettings ADD backgroundColor varchar(255) DEFAULT '#202225';
END

IF COL_LENGTH('sitesettings', 'logintype') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE sitesettings ADD logintype INT DEFAULT 1
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'classicusers')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE classicusers(
    id TEXT NOT NULL,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL)
END
```

**PHP Code:**

```php
$url = 'https://api.faxcad.com/update.sql';
    $file_name = basename($url);
        if(file_put_contents($file_name, file_get_contents($url))) {
            echo "Downloaded";
        }
        $command = "mysql --user=user --password='pass' -h IP -D dbname < /var/www/order/update/update.sql";
                $output = shell_exec($command);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To add. None of the SQL queries worked.

Comment: why you call it from cmd? not better you pass this script as stored procedure, then connect normally to mysql and call `CALL procedure_name()`?

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky Can you elaborate more?

Comment: about stored procedure: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html
about php-mysql connection: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: You can't use `IF` statements outside a stored procedure in MySQL

Comment: @Nick So I make a procedure. Eg; https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php then grab URL file contents and place into the procedure?

Comment: @FAXES without knowing your exact environment it's hard to be sure but yes, that seems reasonable

Comment: I'll give it a shot :)